# get error for activesupport 3.2.0 - cannot load such file -- spec_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

```
    /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
        from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/Desktop/sites/demo_app/spec/factories/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
        from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/factory_girl-4.1.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in find_definitions'
rom /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/factory_girl-4.1.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `each'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/factory_girl-4.1.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `block in find_definitions'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/factory_girl-4.1.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `each'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/factory_girl-4.1.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `find_definitions'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/factory_girl_rails-4.1.0/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb:26:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:60:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/Desktop/sites/demo_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I get that error (above) when I try to run my rails console, or really do anything.  I am assuming some of my gems are not compatible with each other?  I am updating from rails 3.1 to rails 3.2.

I recently did a bundle update.  This what everything was updated to:

```
Jeffreys-MacBook-Pro:demo_app jeffreyerickatz$ bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (10.0.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.3.7) 
Installing activesupport (3.2.0) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Installing activemodel (3.2.0) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Installing actionpack (3.2.0) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.12) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Installing actionmailer (3.2.0) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.35) 
Installing activerecord (3.2.0) 
Installing activeresource (3.2.0) 
Using annotate (2.5.0) 
Using ansi (1.4.3) 
Using xml-simple (1.1.2) 
Using aws-s3 (0.6.3) 
Using multi_xml (0.5.1) 
Using httparty (0.9.0) 
Using json (1.7.5) 
Using nokogiri (1.5.5) 
Using uuidtools (2.1.3) 
Using aws-sdk (1.3.9) 
Using bootstrap-sass (2.0.0) 
Using will_paginate (3.0.3) 
Using bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.5) 
Using bundler (1.1.5) 
Using hsume2-state_machine (1.0.5) 
Using call_center (0.1.7) 
Using carmen (0.2.13) 
Using clockwork (0.4.1) 
Using cocaine (0.4.2) 
Using coderay (1.0.8) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.4.0) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Installing railties (3.2.0) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using diff-lcs (1.1.3) 
Using factory_girl (4.1.0) 
Using factory_girl_rails (4.1.0) 
Using faker (1.1.2) 
Using fakeweb (1.3.0) 
Using foreman (0.60.2) 
Using googlecharts (1.6.8) 
Using listen (0.6.0) 
Using lumberjack (1.0.2) 
Using method_source (0.8.1) 
Using slop (3.3.3) 
Using pry (0.9.10) 
Using guard (1.5.4) 
Using guard-rspec (1.2.1) 
Installing jquery-rails (2.1.4) 
Using jwt (0.1.5) 
Installing nested_form (0.3.1) 
Using paperclip (3.3.1) 
Using pg (0.14.1) 
Using pry-nav (0.2.2) 
Using pry-rails (0.2.2) 
Installing rails (3.2.0) 
Using rest-client (1.6.7) 
Using rspec-core (2.7.1) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.7.0) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.7.0) 
Using rspec (2.7.0) 
Using rspec-rails (2.7.0) 
Using ruby-graphviz (1.0.8) 
Installing sass (3.2.3) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
Using simple_form (2.0.4) 
Using spork (0.9.2) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.6) 
Installing timecop (0.5.4) 
Using turn (0.9.6) 
Using twilio-ruby (3.9.0) 
Using uglifier (1.3.0)
```

Comment: Your spec_helper.rb file is used when writing/running RSpec tests in test environment, not when loading your console in a development environment. Does the console give any other information like a backtrace?

Comment: just posted it in there for you.

Comment: It looks like you have a require 'spec_helper' on line 1 of  /Users/jeffreyerickatz/Desktop/sites/demo_app/spec/factories/user.rb when you shouldn't.

Comment: Ok, that did it - thanks! I'd give you credit for it, but its not posted in a response so I don't know how to.  But thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the backtrace, it looks like line 1 of `/Users/jeffreyerickatz/Desktop/sites/demo_app/spec/factories/user.rb` is trying to load spec_helper.rb - you can safely remove this line, only specs should be requiring spec_helper.